# How to generate package-lock.json only for production dependencies

Tags: npm, package.json, checkmarx, package-lock.json

I want to generate package-lock.json only for production dependencies so that checkmarx only evaluate production dependencies

Comment: However this doesn't resolve checkmarx issue but I got package-lock.json created without devdependencies temporarily by following below steps

 1. rm ./node_module
 2. npm shrinkwrap
 3. mv npm-shrinkwrap.json package-lock-temp.json
 4. npm i
 5. mv package-lock-temp.json package-lock.json

you can make this as npm script and run before commiting code.